# First order partial derivative of complex summation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Considering the below function, what is $h'_x$ and $h'_y$?

$$
h(x, y) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{m_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2} + r}
$$

$x$ and $y$ are some fixed points, the sum goes over a given list of $(m_i, x_i, y_i)$ triples, $r$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering $$h(x, y) = -\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{m_i}{\sqrt{(x-x_i)^2 + (y-y_i)^2} + r}$$ first notice that the problem is totally symmetric in $(x,y)$. So, computing $h'_x$ gives $h'_y$. To make life easier consider
$$H(z)=-\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{m_i}{\sqrt{z^2 + k} + r}\implies H'_z=-\sum_{i=1}^{n} m_i\,\frac d{dz}\Big[\sqrt{z^2 + k} + r\Big]^{-1}$$
$$\frac d{dz}\Big[\sqrt{z^2 + k} + r\Big]^{-1}=-\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+k} \left(\sqrt{z^2+k}+r\right)^2}$$
$$H'_z=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{m_i \, z}{\sqrt{z^2+k} \left(\sqrt{z^2+k}+r\right)^2}$$ Now, to obtain $h'_x$ make $z=(x-x_i)$, $k=(y-y_i)^2$;  to obtain $h'_y$ make $z=(y-y_i)$, $k=(x-x_i)^2$.